# Why is this Kotlin-class an abstract class?

Tags: kotlin, oop

I got this code somebody wrote:

```
abstract class ListItem {
    companion object {
        private var id = 0
        fun getUUID() = id++
    }
}

fun getItem(uuid: Int): ListItem? {
    for (dessert in Dessert.getAllDesserts())
        if (dessert.id == uuid)
            return dessert
    for (fruit in Fruit.getAllFruits())
        if (fruit.id == uuid)
            return fruit
    return null
}
```

Example of a sub-class:

```
data class Fruit(
    val id: Int,
    val resId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val origin: String,
    val desc: String
): ListItem() {
    companion object {
        private val fruits = listOf(
            Fruit(getUUID(), R.drawable.f1_durian, "Durian", "Indonesia", "Often dubbed the king of fruit, durian is an unusual tropical fruit that grows throughout Southeast Asia. A large spiky outer shell reveals a creamy, almost custard-like flesh, which, besides boasting a mildly sweet flavor, is notorious for being incredibly rank-smelling."),
```

I don`t get why ListItem is an abstract class. There are no unimplemented methods.

**What's the motivation making ListItem an abstract class?**

Has someone an idea?

Comment: What is the greater context? How is `ListItem` subclassed? How are those subclasses used?

Comment: The goal is to disallow the direct creation of objects of this class.

Comment: @Slaw I have added a subclass-example.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Thanks. But what's the motivation for such an approach? Respectively what't the benefit of disallowing the direct creation?

Comment: Imagine you have a fruit shop. You can put fruit on the stands, right? Except you can't put a fruit because it means nothing, it's an abstraction. You have to put something specific, apple, banana, pear... This is the software implementation of this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the great example `mr mcwolf` gave, the 'problem' here is a conceptual one: although you could allow for the instantiation of a `ListItem`, what would its purpose be? It has no 'physical' meaning, if we're talking about food items.

However, it's important to note that an `interface` would be a better approach, as there are no actual benefits of using inheritance on the example you gave and it might even be misleading.

If, in this case, `ListItem` is turned into a 'marker' `interface`, it achieves the purpose of not being directly instantiable and helps with generic typing (if used later on, for example) while not breaking some other desired behavior (e.g. putting both `Fruit` and `Dessert` under a `Food` hierarchy).